# How to resolve "Unable to resolve host" in OpenStack Yoga?

Tags: centos, openstack, keystone, openstack-horizon

I’m trying to install Openstack on CentOS Stream 9 by following the official openstack installation guide for Yoga available at: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/

1. When I try to bootstrap keystone I get the following error:
   `/etc/keystone/fernet-keys/ does not exist.` PFA the first screenshot
   [image]
2. When I tried to create a domain using `openstack domain create --description "An Example Domain" example` it failed. Upon pinging controller I found out that the machine could not resolve the controller. Next, I added an entry to `/etc/hosts` that explicitly resolved the controller to my machine’s IP
   [image]
3. Pinging the controller succeeded but I was still not able to create a domain
4. I tried creating a project using ‘openstack project create --domain default  --description "Service Project" service’ This command failed with internal server error.

[image]

What should I do to resolve these errors?

Comment: It said `permission denied`, did you try the magic word `sudo`?

Comment: yes, I've tried that

Comment: I had a similar issue once with the fernet-keys directory. Make sure all directories and files underneath `/etc/keystone` belong to the keystone user and/or group.